# Java how to setup regex for this string

Tags: java, regex, string

So I'm trying to pull two strings via a matcher object from one string that is stored in my online databases.

Each string appears after s:64: and is in quotations 
Example   s:64:"stringhere"

I'm currently trying to get them as so but any regex that I've tried has failed,

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("I don't know what to put as the regex");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
```

So with that said, all I need is the regex that will return the two strings in the matcher so that  m.group(1) is my first string and m.group(2) is my second string.

Comment: Please learn regex, with online regex tester such as rubular.com (the site is for Ruby, but regex in Ruby has somewhat similar syntax to Java's).

Comment: @nhahtdh http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is another good online regex tester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String data = "s:64:\"first string\" random stuff here s:64:\"second string\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("s:64:\"([^\"]*)\".*s:64:\"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println("First string: '" + m.group(1) + "'");
  System.out.println("Second string: '" + m.group(2) + "'");
}
```

prints:

> First string: 'first string'
>   Second string: 'second string'

Comment: I believe you are missing `:` between `s` and `64`

Comment: Thank you, Worked like a charm. I really need to learn how to construct regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:-

```
s:64:\"(.*?)\"
```

### Code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("s:64:\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(YourStringVar);
// Check all occurance
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find() && count++ < 2) {
    System.out.println("Group : " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Here `group(1)` returns the each match.

### OUTPUT:

```
Group : First Match
Group : Second Match
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/PsbNB)**

Answer (score 0):

Regex you need should be `compile("s:64:\"(.*?)\".*s:64:\"(.*?)\"")`